# is_flagged with Views

Tags: views, services, flags

Is it possible to to check is_flagged in views ?

If I send POST request to this URL it works fine http://website/rest/flag/is_flagged but I want do it in Views ?

I am creating REST API using Services Module and what I am trying to check is that whether a Node is flagged by current user or not. /rest/flag/is_flagged this URL works fine but I want to do it in Views.

If its possible please tell me how I can do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it, here are the steps I followed :

1) Add a Relation `Add Relation : Flags: Content flag`

2) While adding above relation Uncheck `Include only flagged content`

3) If you have more then one Flag created, select one for which you want to check.

4) Under "By" select `Current User`

5) Then Add a Field `Flags: Flagged`

6) While adding field select Relationship which you created above in point 1

Answer (score 1):

You could [Create a Custom Service Resource](http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Services/Create_a_Custom_Service) for this, but IMO it's easier to do this:

1. Enable the Views JSON module (which is a sub module of the [Views datasource](https://drupal.org/project/views_datasource) module). This will allow you to get JSON output from a View.
2. Build a `JSON data document` **page display** for a View
3. Add a contextual filter for a node id, this value will be grabbed from the URL path
4. Add a contextual filter for a user id, this value could be grabbed from the URL path, or default to the current logged in user, that's up to you
5. Add a relationship to the flag in the View
6. Add your desired field output and watch the results preview to see your JSON assembled
7. Add the necessary filter(s) to limit the results to a certain user/flag/etc.

You then can consume this "resource" by doing a GET on the page path to your View.